# Replicate the following table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I like the way the following table of contents was made:

[image]

What's the way to generate such table?

---

Ok, so I managed to do the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[left=0.5cm, right=1.1cm, top=0.1cm, bottom=-1cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\begin{center}
\section*{text\\text\\text}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

By placing `\section*{}` allows me to edit the title section like I want, however, it's not displayed above in the contents. How can I display it by using another name for it?

Comment: Added more info. in the original post.

Comment: Of course `\section*` does not appear in the TOC, that's the designed feature of those starred structuring commands. I suggest to read some introductory book an LaTeX

Answer (score 2):

This reproduces the ToC requested by the OP, but due to a lack of information, some features has to be guessed.

- `\(sub)section*` as indicated by the OP is not the right feature for this. The problems and solutions should be `theorem` - like environments, providing their own counter and ways of generating the entries. (In a previous, meanwhile deleted question the OP 'insisted' on using `subsection` and removing the (subsection) numbers)
- The **List of Solutions** should be on a separate page, not just on the toc, in my point of view.

If there would be more background information, it would be a much better solution...

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocbibind}


\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\newcommand{\listofproblemsname}{List of Problems}

\newlistof[section]{myproblems}{prb}{\listofproblemsname}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures
\listoftables


\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listofproblemsname}
\listofmyproblems

\section*{My Problems}

\foreach \x in {1,...,25} {%
  \clearpage
  \addcontentsline{prb}{subsection}{Problem \protect\Numberstringnum{\x}}
  \subsection*{Problem \protect\Numberstringnum{\x}}  % Subsection with heading but no entry to the ToC
  \blindtext[\x]
}

% Now the solutions

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect{\scshape Solutions to the problems in the various competitions}}

\section*{My Solutions}

\foreach \x in {1,...,25} {%
  \clearpage
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\protect\Numberstringnum{\x}}
  \subsection*{\protect\Numberstringnum{\x}}  % Subsection with heading but no entry to the ToC

  \blindtext[\x]
}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\clearpage} % Clear the page after the list of solutions


\end{document}
```

[image]